# How can I access inherited members in a WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, window

I am trying to create a base class for my windows in a WPF application but I cannot access their members in the derived classes. For example, here is the base window:

```
namespace MyApp.Windows
{
    public class BaseWindow : Window
    {
        public int MyProp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is a window:

```
public partial class SomeWindow : BaseWindow
{
    public SomeWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += SomeWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void SomeWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyProp = do something;
    }
}
```

If I leave it like this, the `MyProp` proerty works just fine but I get an error that `InitializeComponent()` is not recognized. Therefore, in the window xaml I change the `x:Class` as follows:
Before

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.SomeWindow"
```

After

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Windows.BaseWindow"
```

Now, `InitializeComponent()` doesn't give me anymore issues but `MyProp` suddenly isn't recognized. Why?

In case it helps, what I want is to have all windows raise an event once they are loaded (the `Loaded` event is fired) and I don't want to write this code for every window I have, so I thought I could write this code in a base class, derive my windows from this and, well, have everything work.

Edit: Here's all the code.
BaseWindow.cs (no other xaml):

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyApp.Windows
{
    public class BaseWindow : Window
    {
        public int MyProp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace MyApp.Windows
{
    public partial class MainWindow : BaseWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<myapp:BaseWindow x:Class="MyApp.Windows.BaseWindow"
        xmlns:myapp="clr-namespace:MyApp.Windows"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</myapp:BaseWindow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the base class of SomeWindow from `Window` to `BaseWindow`, you need to replace `Window` by `BaseWindow` wherever it occurs.

So

```
public partial class SomeWindow : Window
```

becomes

```
public partial class SomeWindow : BaseWindow
```

and

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Windows.SomeWindow" ...>
```

becomes

```
<myapp:BaseWindow x:Class="MyApp.Windows.SomeWindow"
                  xmlns:myapp="clr-namespace:MyApp.Windows" ...>
```

with the unavoidable XAML namespace prefix.

---

This is the BaseWindow class used in the example above:

```
namespace MyApp.Windows
{
    public class BaseWindow : Window
    {
        public int MyProp { get; set; }

        public BaseWindow()
        {
            Loaded += BaseWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void BaseWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the `BaseWindow` class is defined in namespace `MyApp.Windows`, so I defined `myapp` as `xmlns:myapp="clr-namespace:MyApp.Windows"` but now it says that `The name "BaseWindow" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyApp.Windows".`

Comment: I've edited my question as well. The only difference I can see between your example and mine is that you have `x:Class="MyApp.SomeWindow"` wheres I have `x:Class="MyApp.Windows.SomeWindow"`. If I remove `.Windows` I get the missing InitializeComponent error again.

Comment: Your MainWindow class is in namespace MyApp.Windows. So it must of course  be `x:Class="MyApp.Windows.MainWindow"`.

Comment: Silly me... Thanks!